# The name 'SpawnNucleon' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;

public class NucleonSpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public float timeBetweenSpawns;
    public float spawnDistance;
    public Nucleon[] nucleonPrefabs;

    float timeSinceLastSpawn;

    void FixedUpdate () {
        timeSinceLastSpawn += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timeSinceLastSpawn >= timeBetweenSpawns) {
            timeSinceLastSpawn -= timeBetweenSpawns;
            SpawnNucleon(); //error is here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare `SpawnNucleon`?

Answer (score 3):

That's because SpawnNucleon() function is not defined anywhwere in your script. It looks like you are following a tutorial...

This is what the [missing](https://github.com/sandeepkumarp/Object-Pools/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/NucleonSpawner.cs) function looks like:

```
void SpawnNucleon ()
{
    Nucleon prefab = nucleonPrefabs [Random.Range (0, nucleonPrefabs.Length)];
    Nucleon spawn = Instantiate<Nucleon> (prefab);
    spawn.transform.localPosition = Random.onUnitSphere * spawnDistance;
}
```

Comment: thanks man, cant believe i didnt just scroll down a little to the next bit. have a good one

Comment: Oh yeah, it happens once in a while. Glad you got it sorted out. Don't forget to accept the answer. Happy coding!